# Flexslider loads image in html but renders nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am working on a wordpress site that uses flexslider for displaying an image gallery.
The images are loaded in the html, but are not showing in the browser.

I can see the `<div id="slider-1406-585559124" class="flexslider clearfix">` in the code, but has zero heigth.

[The html in developer tools](http://postimg.org/image/vulci0n4h/)

Also, the li's should be like that `<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;" class="">`. Instead they lack the style attribute.

I tried disabling some plugins and it turned out that there was a javascript conflict with the "Q2W3 Fixed Widget" plugin, which makes boxed in the sidebar to remain fixed when the users scrolls.

Now I have disabled the plugin and it works fine. But any ideas on how to resolve the conflict? Because I really want to use that plugin.

[The post with the problem](http://travelmint.gr/%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B1/photos/%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%BE%CE%AF%CE%B4%CE%B9)

The Q2W3 Fixed Widget plugin is currently working on the homepage, if you need the see it's javascript.

Thanx

Comment: what is the problem ??? and where it is ?

Answer (score 0):

Using JS for those widget boxes is a bit of overkill in my opinion. Just use css that's all the plugin is doing.

So it seems they're spit out with the following classes.

```
.widget_text, .widget_like_box {
    position:fixed;
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with Javascript errors and have bloated code.

Also all your widgets are spit out with unique classes that you can apply css too or a general class of .widget which will target every widget.